# scroll view content size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ScrollView` and I set a large image of tree on `ScrollView` and set the 15 `ImageView` of every branch using `RelativeLayout`.

My problem is when getting image only 10 then ImageView should only visible 10 and other 5 should be hide. 1 to 10 image view should display bottom of screen one by one and scroll view only scroll up should not down after 10 image view.

Right now for example, if get 8 for 8 ImageViews display in bottom of screen and if get 6 for 6 image view display in bottom and after all 7th 8th is hidden in bottom of screen but its is scrolling. which must be stop.

Here is my code:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final int height = display.getHeight();  //get screen height 
    // Log.e("width , hight od screen",""+height);
    Rect r=locateView(finalViewList.get(finalViewList.size()-1)); // get               image position on scroll view
    final int touchY = (r.bottom);
    lastPos = touchY - height;  //
    scview.scrollTo(0, lastPos); //set scroll view
```

Scroll is set in bottom starting from 10th `ImageView` but `ScrollView` is scrolling down and can show empty 11th image view. Suppose I hide eleven ImageViews then the empty branch is showing, which should not show.